# C++ list not filling;

Tags: c++, list

```
list<string> Lexicon::startWith(char ch) {
    list<string> temp;
    string listWord;
    for (list<string>::iterator it = Words.begin(); it != Words.end(); ++it) {
        listWord=*it;
        if (ch == listWord[0])
            temp.push_back(listWord);
    }
    return temp;
```

The temporary list is not being filled and `.size` is returning 0

Comment: You need to debug this yourself first and then provide a [mcve] if you still cannot figure out the issue afterwards

Answer (score 1):

In order to get temp list filled, you have to satisfy the following:

- Words container is not empty
- It contains at least one word that starts with ch char